# how to convert numbers from one language to english or forcing the user to write in english only?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to convert Arabic numbers into english or force the user to enter english numbers only, so how to do so?
i.e 123 = ١٢٣ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

For converting numbers you can simply write a function like this:

```
Map persianNumberMap = {
  '۰': '0',
  '۱': '1',
  '۲': '2',
  '۳': '3',
  '۴': '4',
  '۵': '5',
  '۶': '6',
  '۷': '7',
  '۸': '8',
  '۹': '9'
};
    
String convertPersianNumberToEnglish(String number) {
   String converted = number;
   persianNumberMap.forEach((key, value) => converted.replaceAll(key, value));
   return converted;
}
```

But you can also use `FilteringTextInputFormatter` to restrict inputs of a `TextField`:

```
TextField(inputFormatters: [
     FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[0-9]")),
])
```

This `TextField` will only accept English number characters.

Answer (score 0):

I have published the [`localizeDigits()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/hrk_batteries/latest/hrk_batteries/HrkString/localizeDigits.html) extension method on String in the package [`hrk_batteries`](https://pub.dev/packages/hrk_batteries).

Add the package:

```
$ dart pub add hrk_batteries
```

Use it as follows:

[localized_digits_example.dart](https://github.com/hrishikesh-kadam/hrk_batteries.dart/blob/main/example/localized_digits_example.dart)

```dart
import 'package:hrk_batteries/hrk_batteries.dart';

void main() {
  final String arToEnLocalizedString = 'A٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩Z'.localizeDigits(
    fromZeroDigit: '\u0660', // fromZeroDigit: '٠',
    toZeroDigit: '0',
  );
  print(arToEnLocalizedString); // A0123456789Z
}
```